# We divide randomly interval $[0,1]$ into two parts, pick longer one, divide it and choose longer one. Let $X$ designate it's length. Find density.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

We divide randomly interval $[0,1]$ into two parts. We choose longer one and divide it randomly again. We pick longer one. Let $X$ be random variable designating length of final interval. Find its density and expected value.

EDIT

I am extremely thankful that community drew my attention to shameful inappropriateness of my question. I am giving you much needed context to understand my, otherwise ambiguous, topic. I tried to solve this problem by, first finding relevant information about random variable designating length of interval after first division. And, initially, I hoped that some kind of conditional formula could work. It didn't. I am inexperienced random variable user, so, honestly, I wanted rather to see solution , not hint.

Comment: Any attempts? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Indeed, why a PSQ after 70+ questions posted on the site?

Comment: @Pieter21 Well, I tried to divide task into two parts. First find relevant information about length of longer interval after first division, and then somehow, carry it on, because we seem to do the same thing twice. I know how to complete the first step, but I do not have idea how to extrapolate it into second step.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk (Sextus Empirikus) : I have an answer for you.

Comment: @zoli Question is opened again!

Comment: Hint: Let $Y$ denote the length of the interval one gets after the first division. 1. Compute the PDF $f_Y$ of $Y$. 2. Compute the conditional PDF $f_{X\mid Y}(\ \mid y)$ of $X$ conditionally on $Y=y$, for every $y$. 3. Deduce the PDF $f_X$ of $X$ using the formula $$f_X(x)=\int f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)f_Y(y)dy$$

Comment: "I wanted rather to see solution , not hint." Well, wrong site then?

Comment: @Did: I've delivered a third attempt.

Comment: @zoli Why don't you follow carefully and closely the steps I delineated in my previous comment instead of accumulating misleading answers? You got $f_Y$ right. Now what is $f_{X\mid Y}(\ \mid y)$?

Comment: @Did: I don't know, what's gong on with me. I wash my hands, and will jump in again.

Comment: @Did is the correct answer $7/16$?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk Why don't you follow carefully and closely the steps I delineated in my previous comment, to reach the result by yourself instead of waiting passively for it to appear on this page?

Comment: @Did, well, I did try to do this and obtained $7/16$. I am little hesitant because, partly because today and tommorow I have more pressing issues to deal with, and partly because conditional PDFs is something I am not supposed to know at current stage of my education. I know it only from wikipedia and actually I am often not smart enough to use new definitions without extensive contact with examples of using it beforehand.

Comment: Trying to reconstruct definitions one does not know using the present site is at best futile (see for example what happens on the present page). Sorry. "I am often not smart enough to use new definitions" My impression is that smartness is not the issue, rather do you have any definition at hand? If not, where are we going?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk: Base on Did's remarks (and help) I have a solution now. Some of the details will have to be checked though. You could help (yourself) by doing some work on checking the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the first division is uniformly distributed over the interval $\left[\frac12,1\right]$. That is,

$$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}2&\text{ if } \frac12\le y\le 1\\
0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Given that the result of the first division is $y$ then the distribution of the second division is uniform over $\left[\frac y2,y\right]$. That is the conditional probability of $X$ given $Y=y$ is

$$f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac2y&\text{ if}&\frac y2\le x\le y\\
0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

So, the joint distribution of the two divisions is supported by the gray area depicted below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

and

$$f_{X,Y}(y,x)=f_{X\mid Y=y}(y)f_Y(y)=4\begin{cases}\frac1y&\text{ if } \frac y2 \le x\le y\text{ and } \frac12\le y \le 1\\
0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

From here, the pdf. of the second division is

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(y,x)\ dy=$$
$$=4\begin{cases}\int_{\frac12}^{2x}\frac1y \ dy&\text{ if }&\frac14\le x\le \frac12\\
\int_x^1\frac1y\ dy&\text{ if }&\frac12\le x\le 1\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}=$$
$$=4\begin{cases}\ln(4)+\ln(x)&\text{ if }&\frac14\le x\le \frac12\\
-\ln(x)&\text{ if }&\frac12\le x\le 1\\
0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Here is the strange shape of this pdf.:

[image]

---

As far as the expectation, we have to evaluate the following integral(s)

$$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)\ dx=4\ln(4)\int_{\frac14}^{\frac12}x\ dx+4\int_{\frac14}^{\frac12}x\ln(x)\ dx-4\int_{\frac14}^1 x\ln(x)\ dx).$$

The key to this calculation is the simple fact that

$$\int x\ln(x)\ dx =\frac14x^2(2\ln(x)-1)+C.$$

Comment: But *the joint distribution of the two divisions is* NOT *uniform*, obviously.

Comment: @Did: My last (desperate) attempt.

Comment: You now follow the method to compute $f_X$ explained in a comment on main. Unsurprisingly the result is at least sensible (I did not check the details). Re the expectation, one should decompose the computations into the simple steps $$E(Y)=\tfrac34\qquad E(X\mid Y=y)=\tfrac34y\qquad E(X)=E(E(X\mid Y))=E(\tfrac34Y)=\left(\tfrac34\right)^2$$ Then the computations involving densities in your post, once completed, might be used as an indirect way to check that the expression of $f_X$ is correct.